# No Content Object definition found at TypoScript after TYPO3 update from 8 to 9 LTS

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I get this error message

> No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "lib.partnerslider"

after an TYPO3 upgrade from 8 to 9LTS

[image]

Tried many things, don't know how to fix it - can somebody help?
I think the problem is caused by the extension "mask"

I tried to delete all mask properties. I also reinstalled the extension "Mask"

Answer (score 0):

The error points you to a missing TypoScript. So just check in the template backend module (TypoScript Object Browser) if the TS "lib.partnerslider" is available in your TYPO3 9. Maybe some lines of TypoScript are missing here.

Comment: lib.partnerslider is available - the problem ist that the content "lib.partnerslider" is working on some pages, and on some pages not.